# Strip mysql data string with date info to display just Month and Day

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am querying a mysql database and have a tuple of strings returning. One such string has date information for a users post in the form of: 'March 20, 2014, 5:17A.M.

I am using mysqldb to query the database and then using a for loop to assign the data to a variable like so (Our data is not stored in the lovely Django models, I know, working on it):

```
data = cur.fetchall()
for i in data:
    post_date = i[2] # Index of the string that holds the date data
```

I would like to display the data as just: 'March 20'. If I set:

```
post_date = post_date.date
```

I get March 20, 2014. How can I strip the year off here? I am fairly certain that it is doable with out overcomplicating it (ie. importing datetime.strptime stuff). Anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have a `datetime` object right there. The Python/MySQL connector handles conversion to datetime objects. `strftime` is the easiest way to get a specific format:

```
post_date = post_date.strftime('%B %d')
```

Comment: Excellent, I knew it was right in front of me. Much appreciated